# how to connect other firestore DB in android

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code in my Android app:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(FirebaseApp)
```

It is not working.

But the same things work with firebase realtime DB:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseApp)
```

help please

Comment: According to the reference docs, that constructor should exist: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#getInstance(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp) What isn't working?

Comment: I am not able to connect to other firestore DB.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't connect to Firestore yet, it merely creates an object that is configured to do so. Its hard to help with so little information, so there's not much more I can do at this point. Please check on [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since it's the most effective way to get help with coding questions.